# error - ERROR {"code":2100} on Xcode when running Ionic Angular App on iOS 15.6.1

Tags: ios15, angular14, ionic6, xcode14

We are running an Ionic Angular app on iphone with xcode. The cards should show the task end and start date, and a snippet of the task notes. The dates are displayed on iOS 16 but not on iOS 15. The error we get is [error] - ERROR {"code":2100}.

We tried to run on iOS 16.0.3 and error 2100 does not come up and the dates are displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't support Angular pipes. Try using [moment_js](https://momentjs.com/)